# Grep regex to unscramble a word

Tags: regex, grep

I want to unscramble a word using the `grep` command.

I am using below code. I know there are other ways to do it, but I think I'm missing something here:

```
 grep "^[yxusonlia]\{9\}$" /usr/share/dict/words
```

should produce one output:

```
anxiously
```

but it produces:

```
annulosan                      
innoxious
```

and many more. Basically I can't find how I should specify that characters 
can only be  matched once, so that I get only one output.

I apologise if it seems very simple but I tried a lot and can't find anything.

Comment: Your regexp doesn't prevent a letter to appear more than once.

Comment: Will you need to unscramble words with repeated letters? for example {`d`,`d`,`a`} -> `add`, `dad`. If so, this might help: http://www.thelinuxtips.com/tag/scramble-unix/

Comment: @Kobi i actually have looked at that site but was hoping to find a direct solution with grep which means i want one word to be used once only

Comment: @dystroy i think you are write but how can  i solve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `grep -P` (`PCRE` regex) with **negative lookahead**

```
grep -P '^(?:([yxusonlia])(?!.*?\1)){9}$' /usr/share/dict/words
anxiously
```

**Explanation:**

This `grep` regex uses negative lookahead `(?!.*?\1)` for each character matched by group #1 i.e. `\1`. Each character is matched *only and only when* it is not followed by the same character again in the string till the end.

Comment: Thanks @fedorqui, I added some explanation.

Comment: This has no limit on the length of the string, and finds 470 results for me.

Comment: @Kobi: Restricting range is not a problem, see updated answer.

Comment: Another small issue - `\1` refers to the outer group, not the inner one. You need a non-capturing group. Try `'^(?:([art])(?!.*?\1)){3}$'` with and without the `?:`, for example. Sorry if I'm being annoying.

Comment: this does not output anxiously alone plus every other matching word and it diplay words which have double letters

Comment: @hsdhillon: Glad to know it worked out for you, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: @anubhava sorry my reputation doesn't allow me to do that

Comment: Not asking you to upvote I am asking to mark the answer as *accepted*. **You can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick mark on top-left of my answer.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55721/discussion-between-hsdhillon-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 3):

You can use lookaheads to make sure that each letter is matched exactly one time.  It is verbose and requires a version of grep that supports lookaheads (e.g. via `-P`).  It may be better to build the search string programmatically.

```
grep -P "^(?=.*y)(?=.*x)(?=.*u)(?=.*s)(?=.*o)(?=.*n)(?=.*l)(?=.*i)(?=.*a)[yxusonlia]{9}$" /usr/share/dict/words
```